# About subdomain of django

Tags: django, subdomain

Any link about how to use a subdomain as the main domain. Let 's say I have www.example.com. But as the main domain, I would like to use subdomain www.movie.exmple.com.  if anytime I use example.com or www.example.com  it should transfer me to the www.movie.example.com. Any link, a tutorial would be helpful. I really appreciate.

Comment: While you can use, for instance, a middleware to do that in django (see e.g. http://eikke.com/django-domain-redirect-middleware/index.html), this is really something you should configure your web server (Apache, Nginx, etc.) to do.

Comment: needs to be done on your web server or in dns settings